# Connecting 9 Remote Sites with VPN Tunnels

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn, packet-tracer

I am working in a Cisco ecosystem and need to be able to test a 9 tunnel IPSec network over the internet using 10 x Cisco 1941 routers. This is a "hub and spoke" type configuration; where all 9 remote sites (spoke) will connect to the main office site (hub). Simple Logical Diagram looks a little like this: [image: Network Diagram Simple Setup]

I have a subnet plan in the Class A network range (10.0.0.0), and no networks overlap. I have checked both manually and with online subnet calculators.

Example video from a Packet Tracer environment **(For EXAMPLE only)** [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7LwU6H5IGE), which are confirmed working by myself, but only show connecting 2 sites together. The first 2 sites connect just fine and both LANs are accessible bidirectionally.

**Problem:** However, when I try to setup the other 8 sites using the same exact method shown in the video linked above (except changing unique connection details such as a different access list, peer, key and map ID), they never connect.

**Question:** Is there ANY way with Cisco equipment (simple/complex, IPsec tunnel/other) to connect all 9 sites in this scenario to the main network?

If you need any additional information such as configurations, let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is certainly doable, but possibly not on PT.

Comment: "_Is there ANY way with Cisco equipment (simple/complex, IPsec tunnel/other) to connect all 9 sites in this scenario to the main network?_" Yes, of course. You will need to be more specific about the router model and code version. You will not be able to model something like this in Packet Tracer, but there are other tools that may work for this.

Comment: Packet Tracer is a tool for learning Cisco configuration.  It is **NOT** a simulation tool.  Don't expect it to do everything real routers can do.